# Autocomplete does not trigger on field added via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In a web page (ASP.NET MVC) I add an input field using Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag-link', function () {
    var curRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#GetSearchTagsUrl").data('get-search-tags'),
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            curRow.after(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseText);
        }
    });
})
```

Ajax call returns a partial view with an input field that I want to use as an autocomplete field

```
<input type="text" id="search-tag" />
```

On this field I want to use jqueryui.autocomplete

```
$("#search-tag").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: myGetTagsUrl,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var result = [];
                data.forEach((tag) => {
                    result.push({ label: tag.name, value: tag.id });
                });
                response(result);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        newtag(ui.item);
    }
});
```

But when I start typing in my input field nothing happens, seems like $("searchy-tag") selector does not select anything.

Maybe this is because such input field is added via AJAX?
And if this is the problem, how can it be solved?

Comment: If you append multiple inputs with the same ID `search-tag` then surely it wouldn't work as ID needs to be unique

Comment: This happens as this is an AJAX call and call to `$("#search-tag").autocomplete` is synchronous meaning it happens immediately as soon as you call it but at that time `search-tag` element is not added to the dom. You can try replacing the `id` with a class first and then inside the ajax success call the `$("#search-tag").autocomplete` part.

Comment: @Basheer For the sake of brevity I omitted the code where I check for this: no duplicated elements with the same id.

Comment: No need to mark the title of the question as `SOLVED`. If you found a solution, it's perfectly acceptable and even encouraged to post it as an answer to your own question. You may also mark your answer as the accepted answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize jquery-ui autocomplete with the new dataset in the AJAX callback:

`$("#selector").autocomplete('option', 'source', sourceName)`

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Just did something very similar for another SO question:

https://jsfiddle.net/mukagergely/e9wgd2ru/8/

Comment: I face a different problem; in your jsfiddle the first field is already existent and $("#species").autocomplete works. If I put my $("#search-tag") element on the page all works like a charm. If I add it by mean of an ajax call it seems that jquery does not recognize it.

Comment: Is there a working example of your code? (JSFiddle or something...) And by working I mean "should be working" :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

I place the input field as hidden on the page

```
<input type="hidden" id="search-tag" />
```

so when $(document).ready is executed the autocomplete widget is "attached"to my "search-tag" input field.

Then when I click on ".tag-link" element the input field is moved to the right place and autocomplete works.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag-link', function () {
   <snip...>
   $.ajax({
        url: $("#GetSearchTagsUrl").data('get-search-tags'),
        type: "GET",
        data: parametri,
        success: function (result) {
            curRow.after(result);
            $("#search-tag").appendTo("#myelement");
            $("#search-tag").attr("type", "text");
        },
        ....
    });

})
```

Comment: here's a solution that you needed, so you don't have to "live with a hack" ;): https://jsfiddle.net/mukagergely/6jky0a1f/11/ The point is, that the whole plugin needs to be initialized AFTER the input "arrives".